# wordpress gravity form dropdown menu overlaps field label

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using the standard fields drop down menu in my Wordpress Gravity Form. For some reason, the drop down menu (last field in the form) extends all the way to the left side of the container box instead of clearing the label for the field as in all other fields in the form. I've tried all manner of overriding style settings in the Custom CSS Class for the field, but without any luck. Can someone help straighten this out? Here's the live page: https://aicolympic.org/wocf-reservations/

Comment: Your link has a 500 error. If you fix the link or post some code here then we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**
You're missing the `ginput_complex` class in the container that's holding the dropdown menu.

**Long answer:**
The menu for 'AICO Club Membership' is set to use 100% width via the `.sbHolder` class. To override this, you need to add the `ginput_complex` class to the container, which will give it an appropriate amount of width and margin-left. You're already doing this for other fields (example: name, address).

---

Before:

```
<div class="ginput_container ginput_container_select">
```

After:

```
<div class="ginput_complex ginput_container ginput_container_select">
```

The entire field will look like this:

```
<li id="field_3_13" class="gfield gfield_contains_required field_sublabel_below field_description_below gfield_visibility_visible">
<label class="gfield_label" for="input_3_13">AICO Club Membership<span class="gfield_required">*</span>
</label>
<div class="ginput_complex ginput_container ginput_container_select">
<!-- SELECT GOES HERE -->
```

Comment: Thank you Jasraj! It took me awhile to figure out how to correct the HTML code, but I discovered that I could add an HTML Content Box with the revised code for that field, then delete the old field code. It worked! Was there an easier or better way for me to revise the HTML?